# Liquid Metaphors in the World of Finance

Tags: idioms, metaphors, finance

I want to use the terms in bold, to illustrate how these *aquatic* expressions can be used to a student of mine who is a trader. Obviously, I've exaggerated and greatly simplified the theme but I would like to ask your opinions as to whether the terms have been used correctly. And if there are other *liquid metaphors*, equally appropriate in the field of finance, which I may have left out.

> ***Liquid*** assets can be turned into cash which you can ***channel*** into a business; if that venture is particularly successful, investors will
>   ***pour*** funds in, and, if the cash continues to ***flow***, you'll find yourself riding on the ***crest of a wave*** and ***swimming*** in money.  But there are certain drawbacks.  Primarily, an ***overflow*** of cash can lead to CEOs being careless and overly greedy. Foolish investments and extravagant spending could ***drain*** resources, and create a significant ***gulf***. Consequently, the company might have to ***liquidate*** their creditors, and if the economy hits a rocky period, the ***source*** of their revenue could ***run***, literally, ***dry*** overnight. In the most dramatic cases, (the *dot-com* ***bubble***)  companies will ***sink*** without trace
>
> In reality; however, the vast majority of businesses will experience the ***ebb and
>   flow*** or typical fluctuations that exist in a company's economic cycle.   Some companies will decide to merge, and the new company will be able to draw on a huge ***pool*** of resources. The most successful businesses will have no shortage of ***floating assets***, and will wisely plough back their profits.

I realize this question might be closed for being *off topic*; perhaps POB (primarily opinion based) and *proofreading*; but I'm willing to take the risk, and besides I really do need to know if I have used these terms correctly.

Financial English is a new territory for me, I need help!

Comment: Define "correctly". Do they communicate effectively what you intend to mean? If so then use them. If not then don't.

Comment: Don't forget what happens when your *liquid assets* are *frozen*! Nor that *liquidity* itself has *depth* (you can say *deep liquidity*, but not *shallow liquidity*, for some reason; though you can say *thin*).

Comment: @DanBron when do they get *frozen*? When a company fails to pay its creditors? Seriously, I am new to this stuff. Define *correctly*: well, would you consider any of the phrases, in isolation, to be clumsy, inappropriate, ungrammatical etc.

Comment: @Mari, *frozen* describes a state (i.e. *no longer liquid*), not a rationale. The reasons are various, but your instinct is right that it's typically legal in nature; for example, in the US, the OFAC can order the any assets held in a US bank of a foreign national suspected of money laundering etc to be *frozen*.

Comment: Oh boy, and now I remembered about [*solvency*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203608/using-resolve-to-mean-turn-into). I may have to bite the bullet and post an answer. But if I wait long enough, maybe Josh61 will do it for me :)

Comment: @DanBron *laundering*!! :)

Comment: Money is a liquid: http://www.onestopenglish.com/grammar/pdf-content/vocabulary-metaphors/metaphors-money-is-a-liquid-worksheet-and-teachers-notes/147515.article

Comment: @Josh, dude, nice find!

Comment: @Josh61 that's quite nice that link. I'll use that. Definitely. <3

Comment: Is one allowed to comment on the use of the non-liquid _literally_ in “run, literally, dry”? Unless the company sells bottled water and an actual, real-life _source_ is their source of income, I cannot imagine a company's source of revenue _literally_ running dry.

Comment: @oerkelens, literally literally means figuratively now :(

Comment: @DanBron: go figure :( I literally didn't get the memo.

Comment: I'm sorry. I wrote that phrase literally without thinking. :(

Comment: Don't forget the sharks and barracudas.

Comment: @Josh61 I was just about to leave when you posted your answer. I actually prefer the link you posted in the comments, it had concrete examples of liquid metaphors,  a few nice ones which are not in my question. Anyway the fact nobody has said that anything is ungrammatical, inaccurate or awkward-sounding means I can safely copy&paste this piece, and prepare a gap fill worksheet for tomorrow-hooray!

Comment: Although not a fan of “trickle-down” economics, believing instead in “priming the pump” from the bottom, I will admit that “a rising tide lifts all boats.”

Comment: You're welcome to [the *`Time` Is `Money`* metaphor theme](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf), as well. This is coherent in several ways with financial metaphors, and matches `Money` with its next metaphor in the chain, *`Money` Is `Water`*, whence licensing fluid metaphors for perceived duration of time as well.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that trading doesn't come with a guarantee of **bouyant** business and **swelling** profits, and so many companies **founder** within their first years, and are **dissolved**. Their fate relies on getting enough **draft** payments to offset their costs, **shore up** their annual expenditure and **copper-fasten** their business.

These terms are more maritime than fluid or aquatic, but it extends the metaphor somewhat.

Comment: +1 especially for *draft* and *dissolved*. And for teaching me a new word [*copper-fasten*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/copper-fasten).

Answer (score 0):

The financial  jargon abounds in metaphors, and water metaphors are just a  part of the whole set. Water metaphors, as such, are not right or wrong but rather they are  more or less frequently used depending on a number of factors. Some of those  used in your extract are  common, others are less, but they are all acceptable and easily understandable. New idiomatic expressions are quickly absorbed by the financial world. You remember the movie [Armageddon](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armageddon_(1998_film))? After the movie was released,  for a period of time  the term 'Armageddon' became very  popular, and was eagerly used obviously referring to a possible financial catastrophe. Among the metaphors used for money I think the following ones are the most interesting:

**Money as water**:

> - though this is about **flows, sources and sinks,** it  is subtly different from the commodity/supply chain metaphor, since it has natural origins. **Think in terms of dams, rainwater, artesian wells, money “frozen up” in old families as glaciers/polar ice caps, and so on.** This is probably the best way to think about money culturally and socially. Paris Hilton lives on a glacier

**Money as commodity:**

> - **at a certain level, money becomes just another commodity like iron rods or size #9 bolts**. It flows through your systems like a river, in large quantities, can be kept as inventory, depreciates, clogs up supply chains, and depending on the vagaries of the markets and interest rates, it may make sense to hold more or less of it.

**Money as blood**:

> - this is where all those haemmorage and tourniquet metaphors come from. **Money as circulating stuff that, if pumping pressure gets low enough, causes structural collapses and death**. Though most of us resent the idea of the government bailing out fat cats, pure Darwinist “let ‘em pay the costs” opinions miss the fact that the world is not only like an ecosystem of many organisms, but also like a single connected living thing. You can cause a lot of pain or kill the whole thing if you are not careful. This is also the sort of metaphor switch that made Bill Gates switch from wealth creation to AIDS fighting.
> - Lehman Brothers' bankruptcy gives money markets a [heart attack](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/newsbysector/banksandfinance/2965874/Lehman-Brothers-bankruptcy-gives-money-markets-a-heart-attack.html).

[Surfing the money tides](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1348/014466604322916024/abstract;jsessionid=3E53275A9EC0B19DA1A300A5A1EDA492.f04t01): Understanding the foreign exchange market through metaphors.